# WiFi not connecting on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

sir,
earlier i am getting WiFi connection, now not connecting on Ubuntu but the same connect on windows 7. please help me to solve this problem.
thank you
subin

Comment: Please more information: You can see the wifi connections or you can't find anyone?

Comment: We need more information there is a guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide).  If this does not fix you problems edit your question to provide more details as suggested by the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager often has trouble working with Broadcom.

I like to use WICD because it is a simple and easy to use network manager. Its a very good alternative to network manager in Ubuntu and it seems to always work when Network Manager doesn't. To install it just open up the terminal.

To download and install WICD
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk

And now you need to uninstall NetworkManager:
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager

Now you can find WICD in your menu Start WICD, find the network you want to use and enter the information needed, password, encryption, etcetera and choose Automatically Connect to this network. You should be good to go!

WICD may also be available in Ubuntu Update Manager so you can look there first but it is important to uninstall Network Manager completely to prevent conflicts!!